# How to make a drag and drop animation in tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, mouseevent, tkinter-canvas

Currently I have a

```
canvas.tag_bind(tag, "<ButtonRelease-1>", func=move_point)
```

statement for moving my points, which deletes old ones and creates new ones where the user released button-1. This works, but it feels janky and button-1 is used up and can't be used for making connections between points for example. I have tried using b1-motion but it would just move the center to where I first move the mouse.

My question is how can I make a clean animation (like one on windows file drag-and-drop)?

Below is a picture of a graph where i moved a couple of points around.

[image: Graph]

Comment: You could add a bind that detects when the button is clicked, and then, while it's not been released, update the x,y coords of the element clicked until the button release event is triggered.

Comment: Relevant [how-can-i-create-a-drag-and-drop-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44887576)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following example will get you started:

- `shift click` on the canvas to create a circle.
- `click` on a circle to select a circle - it will follow the mouse movement until you release the button.
- releasing the mouse button will drop the circle at the location of the mouse.
- This last action will reset the state as it was at the beginning.

You will need a bit more machinery to create links between circles, and move them around - maybe even a state machine to handle the transitions - but this is a start.

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    radius = 20

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=500, height=500, bg='beige')
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.canvas.bind('<1>', self.select_circle)
        self.canvas.bind('<Shift-1>', self.make_circle)

        self.selected = None

    def make_circle(self, event):
        x, y, r = event.x, event.y, self.radius
        self.canvas.create_oval(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, outline='black', fill='white')

    def select_circle(self, event):
        self.canvas.bind('<Motion>', self.move_circle)
        self.canvas.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.deselect)

        self.canvas.addtag_withtag('selected', tk.CURRENT)

    def move_circle(self, event):
        x, y, r = event.x, event.y, self.radius
        self.canvas.coords('selected', x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r)

    def deselect(self, event):
        self.canvas.dtag('selected')    # removes the 'selected' tag
        self.canvas.unbind('<Motion>')
        self.canvas.bind('<Shift-1>', self.make_circle)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    App().mainloop()
```

Comment: How does it know what circle it selected? With the tk.CURRENT?

Comment: Also I didn't realise that you could do just <motion>, they don't mention it on effbot.org, Thank you so much, tkinter and events are so cool, but kinda hard to visualize when coding.

Comment: Yes, `tk.CURRENT` is a tag that tkinter assigns to the object currently directly under the mouse cursor.