# tkinter: moving an image by clicking

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I'm trying to create a function that allows you to select an image on a Canvas by clicking on it, then with the same mouse button, click on the Canvas to teleport this image to the coordinates of the second click.

Currently I know how to select the image using `find_closest`, move it with `coords` but I don't know how to write the code.

for now I have :

```
self.cnv.bind('<Button-1>', self.select)
def select(self, event):
    self.item = self.cnv.find_closest(event.x, event.y)
    self.cnv.coords(self.item, event.x, event.y)
```

but it just moves the image directly when I click on it, whereas I would like to select it first and then move it with a second click.

Comment: Try showing us the code of what you have so far?

Comment: Tried the `move()` method?

Comment: What you want is _very_ close to dragging and dropping widgets, so I suggest you take a look at [Drag and Drop widgets tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280004/drag-and-drop-widgets-tkinter) to get some ideas.

Comment: @martineau: true, though you linked to an article about moving widgets, not canvas items. The solutions would not quite be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I might do this is to first check to see if any items have the tag "selected" when you detect a click. If there are one or more items with the "selected" tag, move them. If there are none with the "selected" tag, then add the tag to the nearest item.

The logic would look something like this:

```
def handle_click(event):
    canvas = event.widget
    items = canvas.find_withtag("selected")
    if items:
        # move the items to the new coordinates
        ...
   else:
        # add the 'select' tag to the item closest
        # to the click 
        ...
```