# Class providing methods inherited into class providing underlying data - How is that called?

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have a class `Library` which defines some methods on - kind of - abstract data. This class is then inherited into a class `A` or `B` that actually defines the data. The intention is to reuse `Library` with different underlying data storage models.

In Python:

```
class Library:
    def meth1(self, ...):
      return ...
    def meth2(self, ...):
      return ...
    def compute_property1(...):
      return ...
    def compute_property2(...):
      return ...

class B(Library):
    property1 = property(lambda s: s.compute_property1()) #plain property
    property1 = property(lambda s: s.compute_property2()) #plain property

class A(Library):
    property1 = my_property_with_fancy_caching_and_compression_and_stuff(....)
    property1 = my_property_with_fancy_caching_and_compression_and_stuff(....)
```

Is this pattern a well-known design approach? Does it have a name? Is there a recommended name for `Library`?

Comment: looks like a mixin class to me... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful

Answer (score 1):

Your example is leveraging Python's Multiple inheritance mechanism, whereby you add methods from a methods-only, data-free, abstract class `A`, to one (or several) data-oriented, dumb concrete class `B`.

As it separates data-storing (representation) from functionality (methods), it is very **close to a mixin** as [Bruno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41316/bruno-desthuilliers) commented, but with the distinction that such pattern usually brings both data storage *and* functionality. This difference in your pattern makes it not completely [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) (where an object is supposed to bring both) but is **reminiscent of the [Aspect-Oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) paradigm**.

If I were to describe this mechanism in OOP, I'd call class `A` an **interface with default methods**. That would carry the ability to import anywhere some methods implementations, but *no fields*. And I would call class `B` [Data Access Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object)

*Note:* If you intend to do so for several interfaces (*e.g.*, if you were to split your `meth1()` and `compute_priority_1()`from `meth2()` and `comute_priority_2()` from each other, and place them in two separate interfaces), then that would follow [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).

Comment: Thanks for that thorough analysis :-) Is there a recommendable book about those topics? (So far, I only worked through the classical "Design Patterns", but I find it a bit ... well .... not-tought-to-an-end ...?) )

Comment: StackOverflow is probably goo enough. Then you'll need to confront reality to find something 'thought-to-an-end'. Very rarely are Design-Patterns explained in a use-case complete enough. I have read a lot, but ulitmately it is down to: 1) Lift your pen 2) Define what your goal 3) Think hard on the OOP tools you have (Interfaces, fields, generics...) 4) Write what you want your usage code to look like ideally (how to USE the DP) 5) Make it happen.