# The `get_context_data` of attribute of class object

Tags: python, django

The `get_context_data` of attribute of class object.

I encounter `PasswordContextMixin` in [django/contrib/auth/views.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py)

```
class PasswordContextMixin:
    extra_context = None

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'title': self.title,
            **(self.extra_context or {})
        })
        return context
```

I am confused with `context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)`, because it equals to `context = object.get_context_data(**kwargs)`

```
 In [15]: getattr(object, 'get_context_data')
AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute 'get_context_data'
```

How to understand this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the name says, this class is a mixin. It is intended to be used with a view class, specifically a subclass of TemplateView, which will define `get_context_data`.

Comment: ty, appreciate it very much if help some references about mixin.

Comment: @Nakajima https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful