# How do I call a method from an extended class?

Tags: dart, flutter, mixins

i have no experience with extended classes
so don't be shocked... that's what I got:

the 'basic class' I want to extend in my models
to avoid repeat fromJson/toJson every 2 lines

```
    import 'dart:convert';

class BaseModel {
  Map<String, dynamic> json2Map(String json) => jsonDecode(json);
  String map2Json(Map<String, dynamic> map) => jsonEncode(map);

  json2List(String jsonList) {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> _list = [];
    jsonDecode(jsonList).forEach((_json) => _list.add(jsonDecode(_json)));
    return _list;
  }

  mapList2Json(List<Map<String,dynamic>> list) {
    List<String> jsonList= [];
    list.forEach((_map) => jsonList.add(map2Json(_map)));
    return jsonEncode(jsonList);
  }
}
```

and here is one of the class that extends this:

```
    import 'package:bloc_hub/models/base_model.dart';

class Info extends BaseModel {
  final String name;
  final String company;
  Info({this.name,this.company});

  factory Info.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new Info(
        name: json['name'],
        company: json['company'],
    );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap()  {
    var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    map['name'] = name;
    map['company'] = company;
      return map;
  }
}
```

(I'm in a streambuilder and client.info is a json)
then... when I try to call 'json2map'
which is from the extended class...

```
Info info = Info.fromMap(json2Map(client.info));
```

i get this:

```
[dart] The method 'json2Map' isn't defined for the class 'ListPage'. [undefined_method]
```

what did I get wrong?
if I wasn't clear don't refrain to ask me anything

thank you for your help

[edit: bonus question
how a mixin is different from what I'm doing?]

Comment: There are no mixins in your code. Where is it?

Comment: looks like I need to change the title of the question...
nevertheless, shouldn't I be able to call the function from the class I'm extending? implicitly what's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json2Map` is an instance method of `BaseModel`, so in order to call it you must use an instance of `BaseModel` or a class that extends it (like `Info`), like:

```
var b = new BaseModel();
b.json2Map(something);
```

The error message says you're calling it from `ListPage`, so the method is not found.

Alternatively, you could make the methods static and call it like `BaseModel.json2Map(...)` (without an instance).

There are some good explanations about mixins [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful) (with Python examples, but the concepts are the same for Dart). I guess in your example it would make more sense to have a mixin with JSON related functions, since you could use them in other kind of objects.

Comment: I tried your way and works, I'm new to the concept of mixin I'll try different approaches in time, thanks for the help