# Python 3 Strategy / Factory Pattern: Type for instance of class that dynamically inherits implementations of one or more abstract class types

Tags: python, dynamic, mixins, factory-pattern, type-hinting

I'm writing the following class structure:

```
class genericCar(ABC):
      baseCarMethodA()

class specificCar(genericCar):
      specificCarMethodB()

class genericEngine(ABC):
      baseEngineMethodA()

class specificEngine(genericEngine):
      specificEngineMethodA()
```

I want to create a container object that dynamically inherits from many different classes, like specificCar and specificEngine, and others, to construct an object that contains their methods and fields.

I am doing that by selecting the implementation of generic class types that the object should inherit via string name:

```
def getBuiltCar(genericCar, genericEngine):
    class carFactory(genericCar, genericEngine):
        def __init__(self):
            pass
    return builtCar
```

The idea is to build an object (car) that inherits from (concreteImplofGenericTypeA, concreteImplofGenericTypeB, etc.).

I want to do this:

```
def testDynamicInheritance():
    instance = getBuiltCar("specificCar", "specificEngine") 
    # Type of object instance is a union of specificCar + specificEngine
    # but how do I use Type methods to label instance with the proper type?
    instance.<autoSuggests>specificEngineMethodA()
    instance.<autoSuggests>specificCarMethodB()
```

Pycharm autocompletion should recognize that instance is inheriting from "specificCar" and "specificEngine".  So this is essentially a dynamic mixin factory.

How do I work with Python's typing system to provide the proper type hints for pycharm to properly autocomplete the methods and fields from the dynamically inherited concrete classes?  Or am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: What I don't want to do is this:
https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Factory.html#abstract-factories
In other words, create a concrete factory for every possible combination, that might work if we are inheriting from only two classes, but what if we need to inherit from a 3rd class?  There would be a concrete factory class explosion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use something closer to the [builder creation pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), or potentially a [prototype creation pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern).

Rather than dynamic multiple inheritance, you aggregate your tires, frame, engine, etc as components, and expose them as a car instance. That car instance doesn't necessarily even need subtypes.

Comment: I will try to build it using one of these patterns, I will let you know the results.  I think really what I'm struggling with is getting the IDE to recognize that the object I'm building is comprised of these other objects with certain methods, and trying to get it to present an autocomplete list with those methods.  But that's not a language problem it's an IDE / typing problem.  The answer here had some nice use of mixin, maybe I'll try that and see how it works in the editor (pycharm): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful