# How to make sure subclasses are dataclasses?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I have a base class to provide functionality to a variety of classes, and I want to make sure classes that inherit from this one are decorated with `@dataclass`. The following definition results in the `ValueError` being raised:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, is_dataclass


class Base:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        if not is_dataclass(cls):
            raise ValueError('Base subclasses should be dataclasses.')


@dataclass
class Child(Base):
    ...
```

As I understand, this is due to the inheritance happening (and therefore `Base.__init_subclass__(Child)` running) *before* the `@dataclass` has a chance to run. Is there a nice way to work around this?

Comment: Why does it matter? There's nothing special about a dataclass; the decorator just generates some boilerplate code for you.

Comment: @chepner Could be important if you expect to use the instances with `dataclasses.fields` or such…

Comment: are you actually writing a base class, or are you writing a [mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful)?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can decorate your classes.  Here's the idea (adjust accordingly).

**Given**

```
import dataclasses as dc
```

**Code**

```
def verify_dataclass(kls):
    if not dc.is_dataclass(kls):
        print(f"'{kls.__name__}' is not a dataclass.")
        # Do something
    return kls
```

**Demo**

A dataclass is ok.

```
@verify_dataclass
@dc.dataclass
class Foo:
    pass
```

A subclass of a dataclass is ok.

```
@verify_dataclass
class Bar(Foo):
    pass
```

A regular class warns.

```
@verify_dataclass
class Baz:
    pass

# 'Baz' is not a dataclass.
```