# How to understand the `self.fields` in the Class?

Tags: python

When I read this [document](https://github.com/openstack/ironic/blob/master/ironic/api/controllers/base.py#L41):

```
for k in self.fields
```

as the for loop description, it should be a list.

This mean an object instance's attribute `fields`. 
but in Python Base object there is no `fields` attribute, and you see the `AsDictMixin` is Inherited from `object`.

Comment: It's a mixin. It will extent an other base class. So, expect `fields` to be defined in a class that inherits `AsDictMixin` or its base classes.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/533631/476…

Comment: just a note, self.fields may be not only list, it may be any iterable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixins are classes that are expected to be inherited by other classes that should have certain properties. It's something similar to an interface, but it provides partial concrete implementation rather than sheer abstract.

```
In [1]: class MyMixin:
   ...:     def get_evens(self):
   ...:         return [x for x in self.elements if x % 2 == 0]
   ...:

In [2]: class MyClass(MyMixin):
   ...:     def __init__(self, elements):
   ...:         self.elements = elements
   ...:

In [3]: mc = MyClass([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [4]: mc.get_evens()
Out[4]: [2, 4]
```

There's a problem with a readability and code cleareness as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

Mixins are usually designed to extend some functionalities of a class, not to be instantiated directly. And many times they are designed for a specific type of classes and written with knowing the implementation details of that type.

So in this case, presumably it exposes a `as_dict` method to convert the instance of the class where the mixin will be applied into a `dict`.

You need to check a class where the mixin is used as a superclass and you'll find `self.fields` there.