# How to define a new subclass that only changes the parent class?

Tags: python

I have the following simplified class structure

```py
class A():
    def foo(self):
        self.bar()

    def bar(self):
        print("A bar")

class B(A):
    def bar(self):
        print("B bar")

class C(A):
    def bar(self):
        print("C bar")
```

Now I also have a modified version of A

```py
class ModA():
    def foo(self):
        print("hi")
        self.bar()
```

I now also want a additional versions of B and C that have `ModA` as parent class instead of `A`.

```py
class ModB(ModA):
    def bar(self):
        print("B bar")

class ModC(ModA):
    def bar(self):
        print("C bar")
```

How do I define `ModB` and `ModC` without duplicating their entire definition except for the first line that defines the parents?

Comment: You want to duplicate `B` and `C`?

Comment: It is impossible to answer without knowing what your "slight changes" might be, but in general, look at multiinheritance - `class ModB(ModA, B):` might be what you need.

Comment: `ModB` can inherit from `ModA` **and** `B` but you need to get the order correct, `ModB(ModA,B)` or `ModB(B,ModA)`,  so that the mro will do what you need but as previously commented it is impossible to tell. Sounds like it is getting complicated - maybe it needs to be flattened a bit. If you make a toy example that you can include as an [mre] It will be easier for someone to respond.

Comment: Is there anything common to all six classes? Maybe that stuff needs to be its own class which can be used as a mixin class, are there other commonalties that can be put in another class? [MRO](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/). [What is a mixin, and why are they useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful)

Comment: @Błotosmętek That does indeed what I needed. I included a minimal example. As @wwii mentions I was worried which order was needed and if it could even handle my case e.g. that `class ModB(ModA, B)` would use again the base `A.bar` instead of `B.bar` but making a MWE showed me that your order still calls `B.bar`. Feel free to include it as answer and I will accept it.

Comment: In your revision should `class ModA():` be `class ModA(A)`?

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to answer without knowing what your "slight changes" might be, but in general, look at multi-inheritance - `class ModB(ModA, B):` might be what you need.

```py
class ModB(ModA, B):
    pass
```

```py
>>> b = ModB()
>>> b.foo()
hi
B bar
```

Comment: *It is impossible to answer* written inside of an answer - somewhat paradoxial

Answer (score 1):

Based on your toy example here is one way to do it.

```
class FooBase:
    def foo(self):
        self.bar()
class FooMod:
    def foo(self):
        print("hi")
        self.bar()

class A(FooBase):
    def bar(self):
        print("A bar")

class B(FooBase):
    def bar(self):
        print("B bar")

class C(FooBase):
    def bar(self):
        print("C bar")

class ModA(FooMod,A):
    pass
class ModB(FooMod,B):
    pass
class ModC(FooMod,C):
    pass

class BadModA(A,FooMod):
    pass

for thing in [A,B,C,ModA,ModB,ModC,BadModA]:
    thing = thing()
    print(thing.foo())
    print('**********')
```

You have to be careful how you order the base classes notice `BadModA` doesn't work because it *finds* the `foo` method in `FooBase` before looking in `FooMod`. You can see that in their Method Resolution Order's

```
In [15]: ModA.__mro__
Out[15]: [__main__.ModA, __main__.FooMod, __main__.A, __main__.FooBase, object]

In [16]: BadModA.__mro__
Out[16]: (__main__.BadModA, __main__.A, __main__.FooBase, __main__.FooMod, object)
```

While this works it seems like you could get yourself in trouble. you always have to remember which order to use - maybe someone will comment.

---

Here is another way, it flattens the structure out a bit, five bases and you mix them up

```
class FooBase:
    def foo(self):
        self.bar()
class FooMod:
    def foo(self):
        print("hi")
        self.bar()

class Abar:
    def bar(self):
        print("A bar")
class Bbar:
    def bar(self):
        print("B bar")
class Cbar():
    def bar(self):
        print("C bar")

class A(FooBase,Abar):
    pass
class B(FooBase,Bbar):
    pass
class C(FooBase,Cbar):
    pass

class ModA(FooMod,Abar):
    pass
class ModB(FooMod,Bbar):
    pass
class ModC(FooMod,Cbar):
    pass
```