# Scrapy TypeError errback_httpbin() missing 1 required positional argument: 'failure'

Tags: python, scrapy, request, web-crawler

I'am trying to separate my error function into a new python file ,s so that I can call that file in other **scrapers** as well. But it is giving this error:

TypeError: errback_httpbin() missing 1 required positional argument: 'failure'

my class Common_contents which i need to call :

```
class Common_contents(scrapy.Spider):


     def errback_httpbin(self, failure):
```

The main class from where I'm calling this above class:

```
    def start_requests(self):
            
            yield scrapy.Request(self.start_urls[0], callback=self.parse,
            errback=Common_contents.errback_httpbin,dont_filter=True)
```

Help me resolve the issue

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should rewrite your start_requests like this (using self instead of the class):

```
def start_requests(self):
    yield scrapy.Request(self.start_urls[0], callback=self.parse,
            errback=self.errback_httpbin,dont_filter=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to write `errback_httpbin` only one time for calling it for multiple spiders - You can use [mixin (special kind of multiple inheritance)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/547714).

In your case implementation will look like this:

```
class Common_contents:
....
     def errback_httpbin(self, failure):
     ## code
```

...

```
from *** import Common_contents
...
    class YourSpider(scrapy.Spider, Common_contents):
    ....
        def start_requests(self):
            yield scrapy.Request(self.start_urls[0], callback=self.parse,
                errback=self.errback_httpbin,dont_filter=True)
```

In this case `errback_httpbin` from `Common_contents` will be available for each of spider class which defined as `class SpiderName(scrapy.Spider, Common_contents)`