# How to define just a method of a class in a separate file?

Tags: python, oop, methods

I was coding a class with a big method, which I tried to move into a separate file. My idea was:

```
class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    import funcFile

instance = Game()
instance.func()
```

While in funcFile.py:

```
def func():
    print("Hello world!")
```

But I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    instance.func()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Is there a nice way to do this, or should I put everything in one file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this kind of problem.

The most straightforward solution (which is what I think you had in mind) is to factor out the *implementation* of the `func` method to a separate module. But you still need to *define* the method in the class.

`main.py`:

```
from func_module import func_implementation

class Game:  # note: you don't need (object)
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def func(self):
        return func_implementation()

instance = Game()
instance.func()
```

`func_module.py`:

```
def func_implementation():
    print('hello')
```

Another approach would be to factor out the `func` method to another class which the `Game` class inherits. This pattern is also known as a [*mixin class*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful):

`main.py`:

```
from func_module import FuncMixin

class Game(FuncMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

instance = Game()
instance.func()
```

`func_module.py`:

```
class FuncMixin:
    def func(self):
        print('hello')
```

But this is less clear, as you can't immediately see that the `Game` class has a `func` method and what it does. Also you can introduce subtle bugs with multiple inheritance if you're not careful. So in your case I'd prefer the first approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should try `from funcFile import func` in your main file:

```
from funcFile import func

class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    import funcFile

instance = Game()
instance.func()
```