# C++ is there a way to force a set of methods to be overriden, if one of them have an override in child class?

Tags: c++, overriding, abstract

It a design question.
So, I got an abstract class with a lot of pure virtual methods. Sometimes, I realized I don't need to override these methods, because I'm not interested in these functionnalities. So I changed from pure virtual (=0) to a simple overridable empty method. But now, a child class can override one method but not an other related to it. And it may cause problems... Is there a nice way to force the compiler to say, "if you override this method, you should override this one too !" ?

Comment: Why don't you make a pure abstract class and a default child? Then you inherit from the default child or the abstract class.

Comment: Sounds like this interface is doing too much, and should perhaps be split into several smaller ones.

Comment: @freakish It's an elegant solution !

Comment: Suffix the derived class function with: override

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to keep the abstract class and to have a default child class, like this:

```cpp
class AbstractMap<TKey, TValue> {
public:
    virtual TValue Get(TKey&& key) = 0;
    virtual bool TryGet(TKey&& key, TValue& result) = 0;
};


class PartiallyImplementedMap<TKey, TValue> : public AbstractMap<TKey, TValue> {
public:
    TValue Get(TKey&& key) override {
        TValue result;
        if (TryGet(std::forward<TKey>(key), result)) {
            return result;
        }
        throw KeyNotFoundException();
    };
};
```

Now you can inherit from `PartiallyImplementedMap` and only implement `TryGet` if the default implementation satisfies you. Otherwise you can inherit from the `AbstractMap` and implement the entire thing.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use mix-in classes.

You could use mix-in classes to adopt implementations of sets of related methods. Read about mix-ins here (even though it's a Python question):

[What is a mixin, and why are they useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful)

You use mix-ins when...

> - You want to provide a lot of optional features for a class.
> - You want to use one particular feature in a lot of different classes.

which is your case exactly. So, perhaps something like:

```
class Person { /* ... */ } ;

template <transportation_t MeansOfTransport>
class GetsAroundBy: Person {  /* ... */ };

template <domicile_kind_t DomicileKind>
class LivesIn : Person {  /* ... */ };


class Urbanite : Person, LivesIn<ApartmentBuilding>, GetsAroundBy<Metro> {  /* ... */ };
class SteppePerson : Person, LivesIn<Yurt>, GetsAroundBy<Horse> {  /* ... */ };
```

Comment: It's a nice approach. But in real, It will not help me. In fact, my base class act like an interface. I need to feed a renderer, and I have a lot of rendering technics. The renderer only use the Interface. So I put here only every useful methods, and a set of methods is related to special shader effects (all of them are abstract too). And in my example, I needed some basic renderable stuff without any effects. But I can't modify the Interface just for them, and creating empty methods annoyed me a bit. I'm not sure I can achieve that with your solution.