# How can I mix in a Python class without also having a base class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mixins

I have a class, `Mixed` which needs to mix in the class `SomeMixin`. But `Mixed` does not need a base class.

This syntax would seem to make `SomeMixin` a base class rather than a mixin:

```py
class Mixed(SomeMixin):
```

But the more intuitive syntax throws an error:

```py
class SomeMixin:
     pass
 
class Mixed(object, SomeMixin):
     def __init__(self):
         pass
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
> TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
> order (MRO) for bases object, SomeMixin
> ```

How can I use a mixin in a class which does not require a base class?

Comment: I think it should be `class Mixed(SomeMixin, object)` but feels like it's the same thing as just `class Mized(SomeMixin)`. What specifically do you mean by 'base' class and why is that a problem to have it? How is it different from a mixin for you?

Comment: Simply `class Mixed(SomeMixin)` will work. There is no difference between a mixin and a base class in python, other than the mixin being usually incomplete and not meant to work on its own. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful

Comment: @GProst as far as I can tell, the only difference is the necessity of calling `super().__init__()`... still trying to figure out why that's not necessary for a mixin. Per @Wups, that might be the only difference, and I just shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @klutt that exact code produces the error for me in Python 3.8.2.

Comment: @MichaelCrenshaw Sorry. It worked in 2.7

Comment: @klutt no worries, I should have specified. Also kinda interesting that there's a difference.

Comment: You don't need to call `super().__init__()` if the super class doesn't have an `__init__`, which is not seldom the case for mixins.