# DRY with super() in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Apologies if this is a dumb question but I couldn't find it by search. I have Python code to the effect of the following:

```py
class CustomListView(ListView):
    def dispatch(self, request : HttpRequest, *args, **kwargs):
        # ... long blurb doing something with request and super, e.g.
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
class CustomDetailView(DetailView):
    def dispatch(self, request : HttpRequest, *args, **kwargs):
        # ... long blurb doing something with request and super, e.g.
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

(This is in context of Django, but I don't think it should matter.)

These two `dispatch` functions are exactly the same, so I feel like this is a blatant violation of DRY principles. But the problem is because the `super()` is used, I can't figure out how I would write this function only once and have the inheritance work out, assuming `super` is called a lot of times.

What's the best way to deal with this?

Comment: Have you [tried mixins?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#more-than-just-html)

Comment: This [other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/533631/3545273) contains in depth discussion about mixins.

Comment: It's not as trivial as it looks. The *compiler* determines what arguments to pass to `super` based on where it is called. You might have to take care with the order in which the base classes appear in order to ensure that the correct `dispatch` method is called.

Comment: Plus, if two classes in the same inheritance heirarchy want to use a `dispatch` method that looks like this, a mixin is not going to work. There are a lot of differences between putting this method in a mixin and putting it in `CustomListView` or `CustomDetailView` directly. I'd avoid using a mixin for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to mark this as solved, the relevant keyword I was looking for is mixins. There's a couple links in the comments, one to a [past SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful) and one to [Django mixins specifically](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#more-than-just-html). Thanks all.