# Use same sublcass override method for QTableWidget and QListWidget

Tags: python, pyside

I have a QTableWidget and QListWidget that I want to subclass with similar override methods like mousePressEvent(). In an effort to keep my code dry, I would prefer not to have two unique subclasses that have duplicate logic. Can anyone suggest a pattern to use in this case?

Pseudo code:

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class ChildClass(QtWidgets.QListWidget): # Could be QTableWidget
    _main_window = None
    _context_menu = None

    def __init__(self, main_window):
        super().__init__(main_window)
        self._main_window = main_window
        self.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.show_context_menu)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        self._main_window.set_active_browser(self.parent())
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code you would *like* to be able to write?  My guess is that you're looking for a class template but it's difficult to say without seeing some code.  Do your derived classes declare their own signals/properties etc.?

Comment: @G.M. Yes, the derived classes might declare their own signals. I may also want to extend the derived classes as well. Initially, I thought I could just have an abstract base class and swap that out later for either QtableWidget or QListWidget. I know that it is considered bad form to change objects at runtime like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [*mixin*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/533631):

```
class MousePressOverride:
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        self._main_window.set_active_browser(self.parent())


class ChildClass(MousePressOverride, QtWidgets.QListWidget):
    # ...
```

Note that the order of the multiple inheritance is *very* important, as the `mousePressEvent` of `MousePressOverride` has to override that of the `QListWidget`.

Please consider that if you want to interact/communicate with a parent object, you should consider using signals instead, as that would better comply with the OOP pattern:

```
class MousePressOverride:
    someSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        self.someSignal.emit(self)


class ChildClass(MousePressOverride, QtWidgets.QListWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # ...


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.view = ChildClass()
        self.view.someSignal.connect(self.set_active_browser)

    def set_active_browser(self, obj):
        # ...
```