# What are the best practices for storing duplicated data in Django models such as first name, last name, and full name

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have built a project with a React frontend and a Django Rest Framework (DRF) API for my backend. Things are going well but I am quite curious about best practices for data saved against your models.

As an example, I have a user model with `first_name` and `last_name` fields. There is a one-to-one relationship between my user and the two user domains (let's say `Buyer` and `Seller` as an example). In addition, we have a foreign key relationship for `Seller` on something like a `Product`.

On my UI, I have tables that display the data and in general, the majority of tables display the user's full name (`first_name` + `last_name`).

Generally, all table fields I will want to filter by and order by via API (eg. `{base_url}/product/?ordering=full_name`).

I decided that I wanted the data returned from the REST API to represent the table data so I am now returning `full_name` by augmenting the serializer of `Buyer` and `Seller` to have full name using a `SerializerMethodField` like so:

```
full_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()


...


def get_full_name(self, obj) -> str:
    return obj.user.get_full_name()
```

However, I will also need to do this in all places where I want to show the `Buyer`/`Seller` where they are referenced by a Foreign Key.

So let's say we need it in the `Product`, I would have something like:

```
seller_first_name = serializers.CharField(source='seller.user.first_name')
seller_last_name = serializers.CharField(source='seller.user.last_name')
seller_full_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

...


def get_seller_full_name(self, obj) -> str:
    return obj.seller.user.get_full_name()
```

I guess I'm curious if it would be best to store all of these fields directly on the user object (`first_name`, `last_name`, and `full_name`). There is clearly some duplication here, so I assume Django would have a way for me to auto-write `full_name` based on `first_name` and `last_name` without requiring it to be passed in the API.

I'm sure it can be done either way but this is my first project using DRF as a backend and I would rather hear some other's experience now rather than learn myself in a year and have to do a large refactoring later on.

Thanks for any advice in advance.

All the best,

Brandon

Comment: You don't need to duplicate that data (Why would you?) About repeating it everywhere, why don't you just [nest](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) the user serializer or use a [mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-are-they-useful)?

Comment: I have considered going down this road, currently, I'm using default filter sets and ordering. If I do nest the user, will I be able to filter the data through the URL like:
`{base_url}/product/?ordering=full_name`? @AbdulAzizBarkat

The reason I ask is that the table loads data with pagination (limit and offset) so the filtering and ordering needs to be done through the API.

I can definitely do more research on Mixins, thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You can define a property in your model:

```
class YourModel(models.Model):

...

@property
def full_name(self):
    return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
```

Then you can access this in any serializer using `source` keyword argument:

```
full_name = serializers.CharField(source='YourModel.full_name')
```

Here's the [doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source)

Comment: The property looks nice but I don't think I can filter and order by a property in Django right (or at least via API) like `{base_url}/product/?ordering=full_name`

If this is possible, then that's perfect but my understanding was it has to be a DB field to filter and order from a table