# How do I add a decorator to a class?

Tags: python, django, class, decorator

So I'm able to add a decorator to several functions within my code, but I'm unsure as to how to add it to a class.

Here are my decorators:

```py
def unauthenticated_user(view_func):
    def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper_func
```

```py
def allowed_users(allowed_roles=[]):
    def decorator(view_func):
        def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
            group = None
            if request.user.groups.exists():
                group = request.user.groups.all()[0].name
            
            if group in allowed_roles:    
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return HttpResponse('You are not authorised to view this page')
        return wrapper_func
    return decorator
```

And here is the class:

```py
class PasswordsChangeView(PasswordChangeView):
    form_class = PasswordChangedForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('password-success')
```

Comment: Usually you use a mixin, not a decorator. You can use the `@method_decorator` to decorate a CBV, but usually it is not very elegant.

Comment: You don't add decorators *to* a class or function; you *apply* them. The semantics are simple: the decorator takes the class as an argument, and returns something that gets bound to the original name of the class. What the decorator *does* with the class is what you have to figure out, and you can't necessarily apply a decorator designed to be applied to a *function* to a class.

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to work with decorators that work with functions with the [**`@method_decorator(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class), usually one writes [*mixins*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-is-it-useful).

For example for your `unauthenticated_user` decorator, you can write a mixin:

```
class UnauthenticatedUserMixin:
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

and then mix this into your view:

```
class MyView(UnauthenticatedUserMixin, TemplateView):
    # …
```

or for `allowed_users`:

```
AllowedUsersMixin:
    allowed_roles = ()
    
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.groups.filter(name__in=self.allowed_roles).exists():
            return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            HttpResponse('You are not authorised to view this page')
```

and then use the mixin with:

```
class PasswordsChangeView(AllowedUsersMixin, PasswordChangeView):
    allowed_roles = ('group1', 'group2')
    form_class = PasswordChangedForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('password-success')
```

Comment: Hi, thank you this worked. How would I go about doing the same for the other decorator I included, I can't seem to figure out how I would go about writing a mixin for it.