# disable inheritance of some methods

Tags: python

suppose I have a class which has 10 methods,
(i write `pass` here, but assume they would have some implementation)

```
class KlassOne:
    def method_one(self, x):
        pass
    
    def method_two(self, y, z):
        pass
    ...
    def method_five(self, a):
        pass
    ...
    def method_ten(self, b):
        pass
```

and a second class which inherits from the first one.

```
class KlassTwo(KlassOne):
    def method_eleven(self, w):
        pass
```

but `KlassTwo` does not want all ten methods of `KlassOne`,
let us say `KlassTwo` wants to inherit only these four methods,

```
wanted_methods = [method_one, method_three, method_eight, method_nine]
```

and the rest are not applicable for `KlassTwo`
one example could be,
`KlassOne` is `Person`
and `KlassTwo` is `Robot`
and `method_five` is `EatsFood`
so, our `Robot` does not want to inherit `EatsFood`
whereas `method_one` is `BodyWeight`, and let us assume it makes sense for both `Person` and `Robot`, so `Robot` wants to inherit `method_one`.

but how could this partial inheritance be achieved???

one way to do this is by using `NotImplemented`, for example,

```
class KlassTwo(KlassOne):
    def method_five(self, a):
        raise NotImplemented
```

and do the same for each method that is not wanted.

or the other way could be to use Composition, like,

```
class KlassTwo:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.t = KlassOne.method_one(self, x)
```

something like that, and only use the methods that are wanted.

but I would like to use inheritance, and completely disable the inheritance of some methods,
that is something like,

```
class KlassOne:
    @not_inheritable
    def method_five(self, a):
        pass
```

so that no subclass would get `method_five`.
how do I achieve this?

or give a list in `KlassTwo`, again like,

```
wanted_methods = [method_one, method_three, method_eight, method_nine]
```

and ensure that only these get inherited.

Comment: If `KlassTwo` does not implement all of its base class' methods, then it's not a proper subclass. I think the best you can do if you want to use inheritance would be to make them do nothing. As the Wikipedia article on [Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)) says '"In most class-based object-oriented languages, an object created through inheritance, a "child object", acquires all the properties and behaviors of the "parent object"'.

Comment: This is an indication that your parent class is not generic enough. It sounds like it should be split up into two or more interfaces.

Comment: "but KlassTwo does not want all ten methods of KlassOne, let us say KlassTwo wants to inherit only these four methods" then *you don't want inheritance*

Comment: That makes no sense if a class derives from another class, it is expected to inherit all the attributes and methods from the parent class, otherwise, the object design of the solution is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer your question of "How to inherit partially", rather is suggesting alternative in case of we're facing a XYZ problem.

Considering your human and robot example, it seems like your base class is not quite a baseline class(or generic) for what you're trying to do.

It might be better to define base class as *Union* of subclasses you're going to have, and add other Might-need-might-not features like `EatsFood` in subclass, or as [Mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/547714/10909029).

For example, let's say we want to have Human, Humanoids, Monkey and Marcus Wright.

What they have in common: They are human-like entities with human shape.
Let's define base class with what usual human-like entities could do.

```py
from __future__ import annotations


class HumanLike:
    """
    Base class for human-like entities
    """

    def __init__(self):
        # some required attributes or setups
        pass

    def left_punch(self, target: HumanLike):
        """punch target with left fist"""

    def right_hook(self, target: HumanLike):
        """Give nice right hook to target"""

    def walk(self, pos):
        """Walk towards pos"""
```

Now we want to make Human, Humanoids and monkey. Then we can find something common between *Human* and *Monkey*, make such as mixin.

```py
class BiologicalMixin:
    """
    Mixin class for biological entities with basic needs
    """

    def eat(self, food):
        """Eats given food"""

    def breath(self):
        """Give that lung a fresh 'n nice air"""


class RoboticMixin:
    """
    Mixin for Non-Biological entities with robot needs
    """

    def recharge(self):
        """recharge energy"""

    def robot_dance(self):
        """Pull out some sick moves that weak creatures can't"""
```

And then all we have to do would be subclassing these to make various stuffs.

```py
class Human(HumanLike, BiologicalMixin):
    """
    An obviously human like being with biological needs
    """


class Humanoid(HumanLike, RoboticMixin):
    """
    A Human shaped robot
    """


class Monkey(HumanLike, BiologicalMixin):
    """
    They love bananas!
    """


class TerminatorHybrid(HumanLike, BiologicalMixin, RoboticMixin):
    """
    Marcus Wright would be here
    """
```

This is more common way of inheritance - Inheriting optionally isn't an inheritance.

If you really need such, best bet I can think of is to use composition and map methods you want manually.