# Pythonic way of passing on methods when using composition instead of inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, composition

Suppose I have a library with something like the following, where `Person` is a user-facing class.

```py
class SwissArmyKnife:

    def open_bottle(self):
        """...etc...."""

    def open_package_with_scissors(self):
        """...etc...."""

    def uncork_wine(self):
        """...etc...."""

    def whittle_an_intricate_dolphin_figurine(self):
        """...etc...."""

class Person:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.swiss_army_knife = SwissArmyKnife()
        
    def open_bottle(self):
        self.swiss_army_knife.open_bottle()

    def open_package_with_scissors(self):
        self.swiss_army_knife.open_package_with_scissors()

    def uncork_wine(self):
        self.swiss_army_knife.uncork_wine()

    def whittle_an_intricate_dolphin_figurine(self):
        self.swiss_army_knife.whittle_an_intricate_dolphin_figurine()
```

I want to pass along all of the methods of `SwissArmyKnife` to `Person`, since the `Person` will have a `SwissArmyKnife`, but ideally, I'd like to avoid all of the boilerplate code in the `Person` class, since every time I update what a swiss army knife can do, I'd have to remember to update the person class as well.

One way of doing this would be to have `Person` inherit from `SwissArmyKnife`, but that feels pretty awkward, since a person isn't a swiss army knife; they just have one.

Another possibility would be just to expect users to write `person.swiss_army_knife.open_bottle()`, but that's a little verbose. Also, in the actual  case that's leading me to ask this toy question, I've already released a version of my library in which you can just write `person.open_bottle()` and I don't want to break backwards compatibility.

Is there a good way that I'm not seeing to autopopulate the methods of `SwissArmyKnife` to `Person`? What's the pythonic thing to do?

Comment: "I want to pass along all of the methods of SwissArmyKnife to Person, since the Person will have a SwissArmyKnife" - this suggests you may need to rethink how responsibilities are separated in your design. Giving a Person all the methods of its SwissArmyKnife sounds like responsibilities aren't being divided cleanly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your objection to using inheritance is that it seems semantically confusing, you might consider the [Mixin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) pattern instead.  The way to do Mixins in Python still uses inheritance, but the pattern conveys that the relationship is one of "has the functionality of" rather than "is a".

This [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/533631/1539989) has a good discussion on this topic for Python.

Answer (score 2):

If you really, really, really want to do this, you can overload the special `__getattr__` method.  According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__),

> `__getattr__` is called when the default attribute access fails with an AttributeError (either `__getattribute__()` raises an `AttributeError` because name is not an instance attribute or an attribute in the class tree for self; or `__get__()` of a name property raises AttributeError).`

So you could automatically forward any undefined method call to the Swiss Army knife something like this:

```js
class SwissArmyKnife:
    def doit(self):
        print("I done it!")

class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.swiss_army_knife = SwissArmyKnife()

    def say_howdy(self):
        print("howdy")

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.swiss_army_knife, name)

p = Person()
p.say_howdy()
p.doit()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/pysnippet/pysnippet@latest/snippet.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is a clever solution, and does exactly what I'm asking! It does have one major drawback, though, which is that autocomplete will never know that a Person can open a bottle. I'm guessing there's not much that can be done about that, but it's unfortunate, since that's an important convenience to users of the library.

Comment: I think the only way you'd get autocomplete would be to use inheritance.  Autocomplete relies on _static_ properties of the class, so no dynamic method will work.

Comment: ...Or, now that I think of it, treat SwissArmyKnife as a Mixin.  See, e.g. [here](https://www.residentmar.io/2019/07/07/python-mixins.html#:~:text=Mixins%20are%20an%20alternative%20class,this%20feature%E2%80%94and%20nothing%20else))

Comment: Interesting. I guess that's basically like using inheritance, except that it keeps the functionality clearly separated conceptually. I think this might be the solution I was looking for!