# What should I type hint 'self' of functions in a Mixin Class with multiple functions depending on each other

Tags: python, type-hinting, type-annotation

Assume I have below Mixin class, and it assumes the class inherits it has property value. However, PyLance is not happy with this code given self.value is not defined in foo_mixin

```
class foo_mixin:

    def f1(self, a:int) -> int:
        return self.value + a

    def f2(self, a:int) -> int:
        return self.f1(a) - a
```

Then I tried to type hint 'self' with some protocol, like below:

```
from typing import Protocol
class value_protocol(Protocol):
    @property
    def value(self) -> int: ...
```

And foo can is now defined as below:

```
class foo_mixin:

    def f1(self:value_protocol, a:int) -> int:
        return self.value + a

    def f2(self:value_protocol, a:int) -> int:
        return self.value * self.f1(a) - a
```

But value_protocol does not contain f1, so Pylance now is angry with me about f1 by saying

> Cannot access member "f1" for type "value_protocol".
> Member "f1" is unknown Pylance

My question is how should I type hint self in this case.

Comment: Wouldn't `self` by the Type of the class itself? Basically `def f1(self: foo)`

Comment: Given that this class has very specific dependencies on the classes that inherit it, are you sure you want to use a mixin instead of an ABC?  or maybe dependency-injecting a `value_protocol` reference that doesn't necessarily have to be `self`?

Comment: @h0r53, thanks for your comment, value should be defined in class inherits this mixin, so if foo is used as the type hint, Pylance will complain about  Cannot access member "value" for type "foo_mixin". which is basically the same as not having any type hint I think. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That's because `foo_mixin` isn't declared as inheriting another class. If you do that, then pylance should be happy.

Comment: @h0r53 `foo_mixin` is a [mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-is-it-useful). It's not inheriting anything nor being inherited by anything specific.

Comment: @Samwise thanks for your comment. that make sense. I may need to re-think about the design. However, would still be interested to know the best way to type hint self in such situation

Comment: If you annotate it as `Any` then no checking will be done at all on its attributes.  I think if you want actual type safety an ABC is the better way to go though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `foo_mixin` an `ABC`, with `value` an `abstractproperty`:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractproperty

class foo_mixin(ABC):

    @abstractproperty
    def value(self) -> int: ...

    def f1(self, a:int) -> int:
        return self.value + a

    def f2(self, a:int) -> int:
        return self.value * self.f1(a) - a
```

Now any concrete class which inherits `foo_mixin` is required to implement `value`, which makes it safe for any instance of `foo_mixin` to access `self.value`.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the answer. Will  accept answer. but just out of curiosity, do you happen to know if this approach has more overhead than type hint? My understanding is abc will create some overhead, but type hint shouldn't have any impact on run time performance.

Comment: The only overhead is that incurred in verifying that the subclass definition implements `value`. Instances of valid subclasses don't behave any differently.

Comment: `@abstractproperty` was deprecated in 3.3 for `@abstractmethod` and `@property`