# Problematic diamond inheritance in Python

Tags: python, inheritance

Let there be an abstract `class Animal` which is extended and implemented by `class Dog` and `class Cat`.

```
class Animal:
  def speak(self):
    raise NotImplementedError

  ... # 50 other methods with implementation and another 40 without implementation (abstract, headers only)

class Dog(Animal):
  def speak(self):
    return "ruff"

  ... # 40 more implemented methods

class Cat(Animal):
  def speak(self):
    return "purr"

  ... # 40 more implemented methods
```

There is also a bunch of functionality that can turn `Animals` into `RoboAnimals`, which causes every `Animal` type to say "beep boop" before anything whenever they `speak`.

How should one implement both a `class RoboDog` and a `class RoboCat` while avoiding duplicating code? Neither `Dog`, `Cat`, or `Animal` can be manipulated.

I've tried using another `class` -- `RoboAnimal` -- that extends `Animal` in order to cover for 50 basic `Animal` methods, but `Animal` has 40 other abstract methods that need appropriate implementation (`Dog`/`Cat`). If I use composition, and simply wrap a `Dog` or `Cat` instance, I'd still have to make sure that all `Animal` methods called on this object behave accordingly to whether the flying animal is actually a `Dog` or a `Cat`.

Just to be clear, a `RoboDog` returns `"beep boop ruff"` on `.speak()` calls and otherwise behaves like a `Dog`, and likewise with `Cat` (`"beep boop purr"`).

Can you do that in Python 3.10?

EDIT:
My attempts at solving the problem:

#1

```
class RoboDog(Dog):
  def speak(self):
    return "beep boop " + super().speak()

class RoboCat(Cat):
  def speak(self):
    return "beep boop " + super().speak()

  # damn, I've just duplicated the code...
  # what if adding robotic functionality 
  # to animals took hundreds of lines of 
  # code, now that would be a hassle to maintain
```

#2

```
class RoboAnimal(Animal):
  def speak(self):
    return "beep boop " + super().speak()
    # oh snap, super().speak() raises an error :(
```

#3

```
class RoboAnimal(Animal):
  def __init__(self, animal_cls, ...):
    super().__init__(...)
    self.wrapped_animal = animal_cls(...)

  def speak(self):
    return "beep boop " + self.wrapped_animal.speak()
    # now this is epic, but none of the 40 abstract methods work now
```

Comment: Have you looked into [mixins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-is-it-useful)?

Comment: Can you show what you tried instead of just describing it? That would be very helpful.

Comment: @Shiva Unless I missed something in the linked post (which is possible), mixins add specific _additional_ functionality to the base class. What a RoboAnimal needs is to use a specific implementation of a base method to override the very same method. Not sure how mixins help in this case, please do explain.

Comment: @Shiva Turns out I _did_ misunderstand mixins! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a class that overrides only one of the methods you need, and insert it in the right order in the inheritance tree. This is called a mixin:

```
class Animal:
    pass

class Dog(Animal):
    def speak(self):
        return 'woof!'

class RoboAnimal:
    def speak(self):
        return 'beep boop ' + super().speak()

class RoboDog(RoboAnimal, Dog):
     pass

print(RoboDog().speak())
```

Notice that `RoboDog.speak` calls `super().speak`. This means that if you don't put a valid instance of `Animal` in the inheritance chain after it, it will crash if it is called. `RoboAnimal` does not need to inherit from `Animal` because it serves an entirely different purpose. In fact I would probably call the class something like `RoboMixin` to avoid confusion.

In general, the order of base classes in multiple inheritance is important. For example, in the following case, the mixin method would never be called because `Dog.speak` never calls `super().speak`:

```
class WrongRoboDog(Dog, RoboAnimal):
    pass
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for. I was wondering whether the priorities were given like that. Thank you kind sir

Comment: @CaptainTrojan. You almost had it. You made the mixin, but did not use it. Python 3 uses C3: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization

Comment: I had no idea that you can use `super()` inside classes that do not inherit from anything. A very fine trick. Of course, now it makes no sense for a RoboAnimal to inherit from Animal at all (y)

Comment: @CaptainTrojan. `super()` just steps along the MRO of the class, which means that you can insert whatever you want into the inheritance tree. It's a nice little trick that lets you avoid a lot of code reuse if you do it right, and shoots you hard in the foot if you don't.