# Motivation for the convention of appending "Mixin" to non-instantiated python classes that I want to define shared methods in?

Tags: python, inheritance, mixins

##### Background:

The [answers to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-is-it-useful) helped me understand the design pattern and why it's useful.  However, I can't find anything on [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/genindex-M.html) on the term "mixin" or how the notion of 'non-instantiated multiple-inheritance' is formalized.

##### Questions:

1. Where does the term "mixin" come from and how does python know a class is a mixin if the "*Mixin" pattern is not reserved?
2. Is there any motivation (besides convention) to append "Mixin" to classes that I want to use for shared methods that don't get inherited from a parent class?

Comment: A "mixin" is just a class that provides some common functionality, intended to be inherited by other classes and not instantiated on its own.  There's nothing special about it.

Comment: thanks, so the suffix "Mixin" is just a convention to aid interpretability?

Comment: Absolutely.  Python doesn't care what your names are.  Even "self" is just a convention.

Comment: @MichaelButscher -- Python definitely allows multiple inheritance.  Indeed, mixins cannot be used without it.  Java doesn't have it, so no mixin concept there.  (OK, so Java does have mixins, but in a slightly different way.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Where does the term "mixin" come from and how does python know a
   class is a mixin if the "*Mixin" pattern is not reserved?

The term is used in OOP, but I believe it just surfaced naturally, as it the counterpart of what a "real world" "thing to be mixed in the final result" would do; it means literally something that is mixed-in your final result, and changes its behavior.

As for Python recognizing it: it does not. Python only knows about classes, and you can name your composible superclasses as you want. There is no need to add a "Mixin" suffix to their name - it is not even a strong convention at all: if it does not make sense in your project so that it is easier to understand, feel free to name your classes as you want.

A much stronger convention the language does not care about either (except in some few "soft" places) is that "_" should be use to denote private methods or attributes in Python code. Besides that, the only names that Python care about are special names that are prefixed and post-fixed with two underlines - "__"

2. Is there any motivation (besides convention) to append "Mixin" to classes that I want to use for shared methods that don't get inherited from a parent class?

As stated above, no. Just name them as you want.