# Is it possible to pass command line arguments to a decorator in Django?

Tags: python, django, argparse

I have a decorator that is supposed to use a parameter that's passed in from the commandline e.g

```
@deco(name)
def handle(self, *_args, **options):
    name = options["name"]
```

```
def deco(name):
    // The name should come from commandline
    pass
```

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument(
            "--name",
            type=str,
            required=True,
        )
    @deco(//How can I pass the name here?)
    def handle(self, *_args, **options):
        name = options["name"]
```

any suggestions on this?

Comment: What is `deco` doing? Can you show its implementation?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem It just creates a database 'lock' to show that a command with this 'name' has been executed but basically the `deco` could be doing anything just that it needs to be run as a decorator

Comment: I would ask why does this even need to be a decorator? You are using classes, just make a mixin?

Comment: Is the name you want supplied by the `--name` option that `add_arguments` adds to a parser? You might want to invert this a bit: have `--name` use a custom action that defines the class dynamically once you parse the arguments.

Comment: And what does `BaseCommand` provide? `add_arguments `doesn't seem to need to be a method at all, so unless `handle` makes use of something provided by `self` in some other part of the class, I would argue `handle` should just be a regular function as well.

Comment: @chepner `BaseCommand` is a class you inherit from Django to implement [custom management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-management-commands/)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat your approach seems like it would work just that I would have to make all other methods become classes. But I like it. Really clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a "meta-decorator", something like:

```
from functool import wraps

def metadeco(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def func(*args, **kwargs):
        name = kwargs['name']
        return deco(name)(function)(*args, **kwargs)
    return func
```

and then work with that meta-decorator:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument(
            "--name",
            type=str,
            required=True,
        )
    
    @metadeco
    def handle(self, *_args, **options):
        name = options['name']
        # …
```

Answer (score 3):

Your decorator doesn't really need to be a decorator. Since you are using classes, you can make use of the [mixin pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-is-it-useful):

```py
class YourMixin:
    def handle(self, name):
        # Code that was previously in deco


class Command(YourMixin, BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument(
            "--name",
            type=str,
            required=True,
        )

    def handle(self, *_args, **options):
        # Code before calling YourMixin.handle
        name = options["name"]
        super().handle(name)
        # Code after calling YourMixin.handle
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have access to the command-line value when the `@deco` decorator is applied, no. But you *can* delay applying that decorator until you do have access.

Do so by creating your own decorator. A decorator is simply a function that applied when Python parses the `@decorator` and `def functionname` lines, right after Python created the function object; the return value of the decorator takes the place of the decorated function. What you need to make sure, then, is that your decorator returns a different function that can apply the `deco` decorator **when the command is being executed**.

Here is such a decorator:

```py
from functools import wraps

def apply_deco_from_name(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **options):
        # this code is called instead of the decorated method
        # and *now* we have access to the options mapping.
        name = options["name"]  # or use options.pop("name") to remove it
        decorated = deco(name)(f)  # the same thing as @deco(name) for the function
        return decorated(self, *args, **options)
        
    return wrapper
```

Then use that decorator on your command handler:

```py
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument(
            "--name",
            type=str,
            required=True,
        )

    @apply_deco_from_name
    def handle(self, *_args, **options):
        name = options["name"]
```

What happens here? When Python handles the `@apply_deco_from_name` and `def handle(...)` lines, it sees this as a complete function statement inside the class. It'll create a `handle` function object, then passes that to the decorator, so it calls `apply_deco_from_name(handle)`. The decorator defined above return `wrapper` *instead*.

And when Django then executes the command handler, it will do so by calling that replacement with `wrapper(command, [other arguments], name="command-line-value-for-name", [other options])`. At that point the code creates a new decorated version of the handler with `decorated = deco("command-line-value-for-name")(f)` *just like Python would have done had you used `@deco("command-line-value-for-name")` in your command class*. `deco("command-line-value-for-name")` returns a decorator function, and `deco("command-line-value-for-name")(f)` returns a wrapper, and you can call that wrapper at the end.