# Class not directly inheriting but can use method from another class

Tags: python, class, inheritance, subclass

I came accross a piece of Python legacy code at work that I couldn't understand how it could work without errors. Obviously I can't write the exact code here but here is a minimal working example:

```
class ClassB:
    def func(self, txt: str):
        return self.str_to_uppercase(txt)


class ClassA(ClassB):
    def str_to_uppercase(self, txt: str):
        return txt.upper()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_instance = ClassA()
    print(my_instance.func("Hello, World!"))

stdout: HELLO, WORLD!
```

What's strange to me is that, although `ClassB` is not directly inheriting from `ClassA` where the instance method `str_to_uppercase()` is defined, `ClassB` is still able to call this method. I should also note that my linter (pylint) is complaining that `str_to_uppercase()` is not defined in `ClassB`. So I'm struggling to understand how the mechanics of the code works here regarding inheritence.

Secondly, this code looks strange to me. It doesn't seem very "Pythonic". So, as a second question, I was wondering in which usecases such code is useful?

Comment: `my_instance` is an instance of `ClassB` as much as it is an instance of `ClassA`, precisely because of inheritance. It's not clear what you are confused about. `str_to_uppercase` doesn't even *care* what `self` is, because it doesn't use it.

Comment: "although ClassB is not directly inheriting from ClassA where the instance method str_to_uppercase() is defined, ClassB is still able to call this method." I can't understand your reasoning. Why should that be a limitation?

Comment: `str_to_uppercase` can be a static method, or it could be a regular function without  `ClassA` being defined at all. The unpythonic part is where `ClassB.func` depends on a method that isn't defined by `ClassB` at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a mixin and why is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-is-it-useful)

Comment: OP is confused that `ClassB` does not have a `str_to_uppercase` method but has code where `self.str_to_uppercase` is used. Python is a dynamically typed language so this is completely valid. If you created an instance of `ClassB` and called `func` you would actually get an error like you expect to.

Comment: @chepner Mixins are quite common in Python though? How is that unpythonic?

Comment: Because a subclass of `ClassB` can fail to define `str_to_uppercase`, resulting in a instance for which `func` won't work. It would be fine if `ClassB` provided a method  that `ClassA` made use of. This (`ClassB` expecting all its subclasses to provide a method *it* needs) is backwards.

Comment: At the very least, `ClassB` should provide an empty definition of `str_to_uppercase` so that `func` doesn't fail with an `AttributeError` whether or not a subclass overrides it.

Comment: @chepner generally these mixins aren't meant to be used alone, the area they begin shining in is when you have multiple inheritance. The idea is you inherit from a parent class which does more of the heavy lifting **and** you inherit from the mixin which adds more functionality. This pattern is quite widely used in frameworks like Django, etc.

Comment: I don't consider `ClassB` a mix-in at all. It's not providing any functionality to `ClassA`, rather `ClassA` is providing functionality to `ClassB`. (Maybe you could call it a contravariant mix-in; I call it a design error.)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite standard in OO and even has a name: The Template Method Pattern.

The idea is that `ClassB` should define some useful functionality, but only at a high level. Its code calls other methods that it doesn't define, but still depends on.

This leaves other classes (`ClassA` in your example) to provide the fine details, called implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

When a method is called on an object, Python accesses the list of defined methods of the actual class of the object. Inside the `ClassB.func(self,...)` method, the actual class of the `self` object is `ClassA`.  ClassA has a `str_to_uppercase()` so it can be called even though this code is part of `ClassB` (which doesn't need to know `ClassA`).

If you passed `my_instance` to any regular function that expects an object as parameter, you would be able to call the `str_to_uppercase()` method of that object within the function (and that would not be a surprise).  The name `self` in method definitions is actually just a convention for the first parameter of the function which is implicitly the instance of the object calling it.