# Create a link between 2 classes

Tags: python, class, composition, delegation

Is there any way to connect 2 classes (without merging them in 1) and thus avoiding repetition under statement `if a:` in `class Z`?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        self.b = self.a + self.a

class Z:
    def __init__(self, z, a=None):
        self.z = z
        if a:  # this part seems like repetition
            self.a = a.a
            self.b = a.b

a = A('hello')
z = Z('world', a)

assert z.a == a.a  # hello
assert z.b == a.b  # hellohello
```

Wondering if python has some tools. I would prefer to **avoid** loop over instance variables and using `setattr`.
Something like inheriting from class A to class Z, `Z(A)` or such.

Comment: *class Z(A):* may be exactly what you want but it's unclear in your question

Comment: You already know how to do this. Hint: How did you connect the instance of the `Z` class, **to the integer `z`, which is also an object that is also an instance of a class (`int`)**?

Comment: Oh, wait, you want the lookup in `z`, like `z.a`, to *automatically* access a value from the corresponding `a` instance. Okay. **What should happen** if the `z` instance already has its own attribute with the same name?

Comment: "Something like inheriting from class A to class Z, Z(A) or such." Well, **why** are we doing this in the first place? Conceptually, is a `Z` instance, a *kind of* `A` (in the way that an apple is a kind of fruit?) Answering the question properly depends on a clear question that has clear requirements and a clear purpose.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel A is access to garden, Z is tool for fruit picking. There can be alternative implementations to Z.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel You raise a good point with same name attributes. Then inherited attributes shall probably be prefixed or smth. I guess that is the typical use of separate class instances :-).

Comment: Okay, then you definitely want *composition and delegation*, not inheritance.

Comment: Ah, another approach is to use a *mixin*, as described in the canonical: [What is a mixin and why is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, the standard techniques for associating an `A` instance with a `Z` instance are:

### Using composition (and delegation)

"Composition" simply means that the `A` instance itself is an attribute of the `Z` instance. We call this a "has-a" relationship: every `Z` *has* an `A` that's associated with it.

In normal cases, we can simply pass the `A` instance to the `Z` constructor, and have it assign an attribute in `__init__`. Thus:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        self.b = self.a + self.a

    def action(self): # added for demonstration purposes.
        pass

class Z:
    def __init__(self, z, a=None):
        self.z = z
        self._a = a # if not None, this will be an `A` instance
```

Notice that the attribute for the `a` instance is specially named to avoid conflicting with the `A` class attribute names. This is to avoid ambiguity (calling it `.a` makes one wonder whether `my_z.a` should get the `.a` attribute from the `A` instance, or the entire instance), and to mark it as an implementation detail (normally, outside code won't have a good reason to get the entire `A` instance out of the `Z`; the entire point of delegation is to make it so that users of `Z` don't have to worry about `A`'s interface).

One important limitation is that the composition relationship is **one-way** by nature: `self._a = a` gives the `Z` class access to `A` contents, but not the other way around. (Of course, it's also possible to build the relationship in both directions, but this will require some planning ahead.)

"Delegation" means that we use some scheme in the code, so that looking something up in a `Z` instance finds it in the composed `A` instance when necessary. There are multiple ways to achieve this in Python, at least two of which are worth mentioning:

#### Explicit delegation per attribute

We define a separate `property` in the `Z` class, for each attribute we want to delegate. For example:

```
    # within the `Z` class
    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a.a
    # The setter can also be omitted to make a read-only attribute;
    # alternately, additional validation logic can be added to the function.
    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        self._a.a = value
```

For methods, using the same `property` approach should work, but it may be simpler to make a wrapper function and calling it:

```
    def action(self):
        return self._a.action()
```

#### Delegation via `__getattr__`

The `__getattr__` magic ("dunder") method allows us to provide fallback logic for looking up an attribute in a class, if it isn't found by the normal means. We can use this for the `Z` class, so that it will try looking within its `_a` if all else fails. This looks like:

```
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self._a, name)
```

Here, we use the free function `getattr` to look up the name dynamically within the `A` instance.

### Using inheritance

This means that each `Z` instance will, conceptually, be a *kind of* `A` instance - classes represent types, and inheriting `Z` from `A` means that it will be a *subtype* of `A`.

We call this an "is-a" relationship: every `Z` instance *is* an `A` instance. More precisely, a `Z` instance should *be usable anywhere* that an `A` instance could be used, but also `Z` might contain additional data and/or use different implementations.

This approach looks like:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        self.b = self.a + self.a

    def action(self): # added for demonstration purposes.
        return f'{self.z.title()}, {self.a}!'

class Z(A):
    def __init__(self, z, a):
        # Use `a` to do the `A`-specific initialization.
        super().__init__(a)
        # Then do `Z`-specific initialization.
        self.z = z
```

The `super` function is magic that finds the `A.__init__` function, and calls it as a method on the `Z` instance that's currently being initialized. (That is: `self` will be the same object for both `__init__` calls.)

This is clearly *more convenient* than the delegation and composition approach. Our `Z` instance *actually has* `a` and `b` attributes as well as `z`, and also actually has a `action` method. Thus, code like `my_z.action()` will use the method from the `A` class, and accessing the `a` and `b` attributes of a `Z` instance works - because the `Z` instance *actually directly contains* that data.

Note in this example that the code for `action` now tries to use `self.z`. this won't work for an `A` instance constructed directly, but it does work when we construct a `Z` and call `action` on it:

```
>>> A('world').action()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in action
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'z'
>>> Z('hello', 'world').action()
'Hello, world!'
```

We say that such an `A` class, which doesn't properly function on its own, is *abstract*. (There are more tools we can use to prevent accidentally creating an unusable base `A`; these are outside the scope of this answer.)

This convenience comes with serious implications for design. It can be hard to reason about deep inheritance structures (where the `A` also inherits from `B`, which inherits from `C`...) and especially about multiple inheritance (`Z` can inherit from `B` as well as `A`). Doing these things requires careful planning and design, and a more detailed understanding of how `super` works - beyond the scope of this answer.

Inheritance is also *less flexible*. For example, when the `Z` instance composes an `A` instance, it's easy to swap that `A` instance out later for another one. Inheritance doesn't offer that option.

### Using mixins

Essentially, using a mixin means using inheritance (generally, multiple inheritance), *even though we conceptually want a "has-a" relationship*, because the convenient usage patterns are more important than the time spent designing it all up front. It's a complex, but powerful design pattern that essentially lets us build a new class from component parts.

Typically, mixins will be abstract (in the sense described in the previous section). Most examples of mixins also won't contain data attributes, but only methods, because they're generally designed specifically to implement some functionality. (In some programming languages, when using multiple inheritance, only one base class is allowed to contain data. However, this restriction is not necessary and would make no sense in Python, because of how objects are implemented.)

One specific technique common with mixins is that the first base class listed will be an actual "base", while everything else is treated as "just" an abstract mixin. To keep things organized while initializing all the mixins based on the original `Z` constructor arguments, we use keyword arguments for everything that will be passed to the mixins, and let each mixin use what it needs from the `**kwargs`.

```
class Root:
    # We use this to swallow up any arguments that were passed "too far"
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

class ZBase(Root):
    def __init__(self, z, **kwargs):
        # a common pattern is to just accept arbitrary keyword arguments
        # that are passed to all the mixins, and let each one sort out
        # what it needs.    
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.z = z

class AMixin(Root):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # This `super()` call is in case more mixins are used.
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.a = kwargs['a']
        self.b = self.a + self.a

    def func(self): # This time, we'll make it do something
        return f'{self.z.title()}, {self.a}!'

# We combine the base with the mixins by deriving from both.
# Normally there is no reason to add any more logic here.
class Z(ZBase, AMixin): pass
```

We can use this like:

```
>>> # we use keyword arguments for all the mixins' arguments
>>> my_z = Z('hello', a='world')
>>> # now the `Z` instance has everything defined in both base and mixin:
>>> my_z.func()
'Hello, world!'
>>> my_z.z
'hello'
>>> my_z.a
'world'
>>> my_z.b
'worldworld'
```

The code in `AMixin` can't stand on its own:

```
>>> AMixin(a='world').func()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in func
AttributeError: 'AMixin' object has no attribute 'z'
```

but when the `Z` instance has both `ZBase` and `AMixin` as bases, and is used to call `func`, the `z` attribute can be found - because now `self` is a `Z` instance, which has that attribute.

The `super` logic here is a bit tricky. The details are beyond the scope of this post, but suffice to say that with mixin classes that are set up this way, `super` will forward to the *next, sibling* base of `Z`, as long as there is one. It will do this no matter what order the mixins appear in; the `Z` instance determines the order, and `super` calls whatever is "next in line". When all the bases have been consulted, next in line is `Root`, which is just there to intercept the `kwargs` (since the last mixin doesn't "know" it's last, and passes them on). This is necessary because otherwise, next in line would be `object`, and `object.__init__` raises an exception if there are any arguments.

For more details, see [What is a mixin and why is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a trivial example of class inheritance that may help you to understand:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self._a = a
        self._b = self.a + self.a

class Z(A):
    def __init__(self, z, a):
        super().__init__(a)
        self._z = z

clazz = Z('Hello', 'world')

print(clazz._z, clazz._a)
```

Comment: It would be great if you actually include what `super` does and it's role in inheritance of the parent class and its children.

Comment: Thanks for reply. This however requires to pass each class A attribute instead of passing the instance of class A and inheriting from instance. If there were more attributes in class A, it would be quite wordly.

Comment: The `A` *constructor arguments* are passed, not attributes. This is so that they can be used to construct the `A` "base", which doesn't exist yet. If you wanted an approach that "passes the instance of class A", you'd have to **have** that instance first, which would still require listing all those same parameters.

Comment: I edited the example to highlight the fact that, given that the `A` class computes the `b` attribute in `__init__`, it doesn't need to be passed around anywhere when creating the `Z`. Only `a` is passed *because `A.__init__` demands an `a` value*.