# OOP alternative structure in TKinter

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I am kind of new to OOP and have been making a few Tkinter applications in Python.

My way to create a GUI is to create only one class with all the graphical part in the constructor function and have instance methods for all the "commands" triggered within the constructor function.

```
#Example
class GUI:
   
    def __init__(self,master):
        # Code for buttons, frames commands etc.
    def command1(self):
        # Do stuff
```

Is there a way I can create multiple classes to make the code more readable?
I know it will not affect the actual performance of the application and will still work the same way.
Although I wanted to learn to write better more readable code and dividing everything into classes. My aim would be to create a base class for the graphical stuff and other (static)classes with various functions for when commands are called.

I tried to do the following using inheritance and had no success:

```
#Example

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x350"

class GUI:
   
    def __init__(self,master):
        # Code for buttons, frames commands etc.
        # When calling a command specific_commands.command1()

class specific_commands(GUI):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super().__init__(self,master)
    def command1 (self):
        #Do stuff

GUI(root)

root.mainloop()
```

What would be your suggestion when trying to do this?
Is there another better way I can do this?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by "static class"? That is not standard terminology in Python

Comment: Sorry, I meant a class with static methods, so that you do not need to instantiate it to call methods. Possibly still not a standard in Python I guess?

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to use *mixins* - classes that are designed to augment a base class rather than be used as standalone objects.

Notice how, in the following example, the commands in `Commands` are able to use `self` to refer to the base class (eg: `self.name`)

```
import tkinter as tk

class CommandsMixin:
    def command1(self):
        print(f"hello, {self.name}")

class GUI(CommandsMixin):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.name = "world"
        button = tk.Button(master, text="Click me", command=self.command1)
        button.pack()

root = tk.Tk()
gui = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

You can use multiple classes as mixins. For example, you could have one class for I/O, one for dealing with external processes, etc. You just include all classes when you define the GUI class:

```
class GUI(CommandsMixin, OtherMixin):
    ...
```

For more information see [What is a mixin and why is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533631/what-is-a-mixin-and-why-is-it-useful)

---

Another solution is to leave the classes as distinct entities, then instantiate them and pass the entities around as arguments to the other classes that need them.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Commands:
    def __init__(self, master, gui):
        self.gui = gui
        self.master = master

    def command1(self):
        print(f"hello, {self.gui.name}")

class GUI():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.name = "world"
        self.commands = Commands(master=master, gui=self)
        button = tk.Button(master, text="Click me", command=self.commands.command1)
        button.pack()

root = tk.Tk()
gui = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

> to create a base class for the graphical stuff and other
> (static)classes with various functions for when commands are called.

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for things called *Mixin classes* or in short *mixins*, it bundles a set of methods for reuse.