# overriding virtual function from several base classes

Tags: c++, standards

Assuming I have code like this:

```
struct Base1 {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct Base2 {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct Derived : Base1, Base2 {
    void foo() override {}
};
```

I am trying to produce a single override for several functions of different base classes with same name/signature.

Is such an overriding legal and well-defined in c++?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Inheritance from two derived classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254673/multiple-inheritance-from-two-derived-classes)

Comment: Yes, it is legal and well defined...

Comment: @kamituel, my question is not about virtual inheritance

Comment: Did you get something unexpected when you tried it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is such an overriding legal and well-defined in c++?

Yes, it is perfectly legal and well defined as long as you override the virtual function in the derived class.
If you create an object of `Derived` structure and invoke the `foo` function it will invoke the overridden function.

The compiler will always search the called function from local to the global scope. So here compiler will check if `foo` is defined in the Derived scope if not found it will check in the Base scope and since you have provided the definition of `foo` in the derived scope the compiler won't check Base scope.

Try this code and you will get a better idea.
The output will be **This is derived**.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Base1 {
    virtual void foo() {
        cout << "This is base1" << endl;
    }
};

struct Base2 {
    virtual void foo() {
        cout << "This is base2" << endl;
    }
};

struct Derived : Base1, Base2 {
    void foo() {
        cout << "This is derived" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
    d.foo();
    return 0;
}
```