# How to inherit from a class that implement an interface which is shared with other interface

Tags: c++, interface, multiple-inheritance

I have this sample code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Interface1
{
    virtual int getID()=0;
};

struct Interface2 : Interface1
{
    virtual int add(int a,int b)=0;
};

struct Base1 : Interface1
{
     virtual int getID() override { return 1; }
};

struct myClass: Interface2, Base1
{
    virtual int add(int a,int b) override { return a+b; }
};

int main()
{
    myClass c;     
    std::cout << c.add(0, 1) << "\n";
}
```

the idea is that `myClass` is based on `Interface2`, but uses `Base1` as an implementation of Interface1. when I compile this code, I am getting this error:

```
getId is ambiguous.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254673/multiple-inheritance-from-two-derived-classes

Comment: @mans: I've simplified your snipet (replaced class by struct, get rid of all that public noise). I hope this is an improvement, rollback it if you disagree.

Comment: @mans, I've fluffed it up further with an `int main()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that `myClass` inherits two times from `Interface1` (once from `Interface1`, once from `Base1`), thus inheriting two pure virtual functions (`myClass::getID` and `Base1::getID`). Since only one of them is implemented, if you try and create a `myClass` object, the compiler complains about `myClass` being an abstract type. And it is right.

The solution (other than using simpler inheritance) would be to make your classes inherit from `Interface1` virtually:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Interface1
{
    virtual int getID()=0;
};

struct Interface2 : virtual Interface1
{
    virtual int add(int a,int b)=0;
};

struct Base1 : virtual Interface1
{
     virtual int getID() override { return 1; }
};

struct myClass: Interface2, Base1
{
    virtual int add(int a,int b) override { return a+b; }
};

int main()
{
    myClass c;
    std::cout << c.getID() << "\n"; // prints 1
}
```

Comment: this works, but it give me a warning that getID is inherited by dominance. I checked for this message and it is not important and can be ignored. Is there any way to make sure that this warning doesn't show during compilation?

Comment: @mans silence it with a pragma, but I'd rather let it be: this kind of inheritance pattern is fairly weak and fragile; it might prevent someone to break it someday and get the hell of an UB.